# Do I need a loop to display an object that attached to posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I created a picture for each post. It takes inputs at the post creat/edit step, then, calculates in a Class and generates the picture. The inputs are saved into the post meta. 
Now I need to display the picture after publish the post.

From the editing page, I can see the Class works perfectly and generates the right picture. I think, when displaying the post, the first step is to require the inputs that saved in post meta, but each post has a picture, how the class work through them. So, my guess is to make a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need separate loop to access post meta. You can use [`get_the_ID()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID) in main loop to retrieve ID of current post and then use it in [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve your data.